# mod rewrite -new.php to /new

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite any page url which contains `-new.php` to the `/new`

For example:

```
example.com/page-new.php
```

to

```
example.com/page/new
```

I am able to remove the ending .php with following rule, but I can't figure out how to match the `-new`.

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule actually adds .php to the end.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)-new\.php$ $1/new [NC,L]
```

removes -new.php and changes it to /new

---

**EDIT:**

After a while of thinking, if you want users to get redirected, use above and add "R=301" to the brackets as third parameter.

OR, if you actually have links in */page/new* schema and files in *-new.php* schema, then you actually wants to remowe **/new** and add **-new.php**. If so, then you asked wrong question. Here you go:

**EDIT 2:**

You also want to redirect */page* to *page.php*. Now you can do this in two ways:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/new$ $1-new.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

OR

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/new$ $1-new [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

First one are two separate rules, first for /new URLs and then for any other. 

Second code is like "first change /new to -new, and then apply next rule"

If you want rule to apply only to urls without dots or anything, then replace **(.*)** with any other rule like for example **([^\.]*)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. my original links are `page.php` and `page-new.php`. I want to link them in my code as `/page` and `/page/new`. The second rule which you suggested does exactly what I want, however it does not rewrite `page.php` to `/page` (my code above was doing that). I cannot combine my rule with your rule.

Comment: Check now, I've edited scripts. Order of rules is crucial here. If you apply .php first, then rule checking for "/new" at the end won't trigger.